# How can I set up a keyboard shortcut so that Ctrl+Backspace = Del?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, kubuntu

As an old mac user, I am used to hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, and the effect is the same as if I pressed <kbd>Del</kbd>. I have recently purchased an Asus N53SV laptop which has replaced my MacBook, but unfortunately this laptop has a very annoying keyboard layout, where the <kbd>Del</kbd> key is in a non standard position, and moreover it is TINY.

Is it possible to get the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> combination to issue a <kbd>Del</kbd> and how would I do this?

Using Kubuntu, but I believe this is to be done at X level, not at desktop, am I right?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about Ctrl+BackSpace, but xmodmap could be used to create the shortcut Sift+BackSpace = Delete.

Comment: Followinf computermacgyver, here's a link with all that information, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts but I not sure how to accomplish your desired shortcut though.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubuntu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> by default is assigned to the action "Delete Word Backwards" which is used by some applications. You can overwrite this, though.

---

One solution was to install [xautomation](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xautomation) [image: Install xautomation] and then create a shortcut for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> which runs `xte 'key Delete'`:

- Open a **terminal** (i.e. Konsole) and run `sudo apt-get install xautomation`.
- Open **Custom Shortcuts** via the search menu.
- Click `Edit` → `New` → `Global Shortcut` → `Command/URL`. Name the new shortcut.
- Go to the `Trigger` tab, click the input button (`None`) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Then click onto `Reassign`.

  [image]
- Go to the `Action` tab and enter `xte 'key Delete'`.
- Click Apply. Ready.

  [image]

([More](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte) about `xte` which is part of `xautomation`.)

---

To assign a new shortcut to "Delete Word Backwards" add a custom combination to that action within **Standard Keyboard Shortcuts**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this help you? [Linky](http://lifehacker.com/256955/configure-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu) Can create your own short cuts. Don't know if you need to do it at X level. Might be able to configure it using that guide.

Either that or something like this, [Linky](http://xmacro.sourceforge.net/). as you said at X level configuration. Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** KDE has has its own short cuts in system settings can it be done from in there. Im not at my PC just now at work PC but I use KDE at home.

Bill

Comment: Looks nice, unfortunately it's for Gnome only: I am talking about Kubuntu, therefore KDE! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Updated. Can you not use the short cuts in system settings to create this?