# Map function+backspace to delete

Tags: 12.10, xorg, shortcut-keys, keyboard, xmodmap

I'm used to Apple laptops, on which <kbd>Function</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Delete</kbd>. I'm also okay with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

Is there a way to obtain this? Note, I'm using Xmonad and have some keyboard modifications set up with `xmodmap` but have very little understanding of how it works.

I've tried `xmodmap -e "keycode 22 = BackSpace KP_Delete BackSpace BackSpace"`, which works in some applications but is ignored by my terminal.

I've seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78769/how-can-i-set-up-a-keyboard-shortcut-so-that-ctrlbackspace-del) but it seems KDE-specific. I would prefer not to have to use some GUI.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 GNOME on a Macbook(10,1). fn+BackSpace works as Delete by default. I tried to bind Shift+BackSpace to Delete using

    xmodmap -e 'keycode 22 = BackSpace Delete'

but that did not work. In applications Shift+BackSpace did nothing and in the terminal it would output ~2.

Comment: It's weird that this question is not anwered.

Comment: @StevenRoose Are you looking for an answer to this?

Comment: Why else would I open a bounty?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.  The function key itself doesn’t sent a key code, it modifies the code that is sent by the key it's pressed in combination with.  That is, it's implemented by the keyboard, not the OS. There isn't a function-backspace code on most keyboards.

You can check this on your keyboard using the showkey command.  Run showkey as root and try pressing various keys with, and without, the function key.

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful tutorial here

http://blacketernal.wordpress.com/set-up-key-mappings-with-xmodmap/

Quite simple solution with different approach, and it was solving my problem

Comment: I've tried numerous tutorials. The Fn key does not seem to be mappable. I've been trying to get it working with Shift or Alt now, doesn't work either.

Comment: This does not solve the question and link only posts are not answers